# Android - Store custom objects in XML Resource file

Tags: java, android, xml, object, android-resources

I have a custom object in Java called Number with 4 String attributes.
Now, for creating an array of that object I have to write it in Java like so:

```
Number[] numbersArray = {
    new Number("attr 1","attr 2","attr 3","attr 4");
};
```

I want to store these objects in an XML resource file, for example:

```
<number-array>
    <number>
        <string>attr 1</string>
        <string>attr 2</string>
        <string>attr 3</string>
        <string>attr 4</string>
    </number>
</number-array>
```

Is there any way to do so? Basically, I want to populate the numbersArray in Java file using this XML resource file. Waiting for replies.

Comment: You can use strings.xml file to store your custom objects

Comment: If I store the object that I have described in the question, how can I access it in java code?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as described in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray

Here's a second example for String arrays: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Comment: For using this, I have to use a different array for each attribute. I want something similar to the one I have written in the question.

Comment: Ok, got it. The only thing I can think of is parsing predefined strings as an array.

Comment: XML: `<string-array name="number-array"><item>attr 1;attr 2;attr 3</string-array>`. Then you could create your numbersArray by `res.getStringArray(R.array.number_array).split(";");`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think this is what I'm looking for. Will let you know after trying it out.

Comment: Your welcome. I forgot to close the item element, sorry abot that. `<string-array name="number-array"><item>attr 1;attr 2;attr 3</item></string-array>`

Answer (score 0):

Insert those objects in your strings.xml as below:-

```
<integer-array name="studentIds"> // here you can defile string-array also
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
</integer-array>
```

now retrieve those objects using below line:-

```
getResources().getIntArray(R.array.studentIds); 
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.studentIds);
```

Comment: I want to use an alternative for `new Number("attr 1","attr 2","attr 3","attr 4");` in form of XML.
Using this method will return me a String[] containing {"attr 1", "attr 2", "attr 3", "attr 4"}.

Comment: Yeah as I said you can define your string array in xml file and when you retrieve that array it will return string[ ] using this line:- getResources().getStringArray(R.array.studentIds);

Comment: I don't want an array. I want to initialize Number object using XML.

Comment: Okay it's little bit confusing, if I am not getting you wrong then you want to store numbers in xml and then it should be returned in string[ ], right ???

Comment: No, it should be returned in Number[]. Where Number is an object containing 4 strings.

Answer (score -1):

Define a string variable in strings.xml file inside res/values folder.

```
<resources>
    <string name="numbers">attr 1,attr 2,attr 3,attr 4</string>
</resources>
```

Now retrieve the String and initilize the Number[] array in your activity.

```
String values[] = getString(R.string.numbers).split(",");
Number[] numbers = new Number[values.length];

for(int i=0; i< values.length; i++){

    numbers[i] = new Number(values[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.